# Mutating state in vuex

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm trying to make an api call to my DB and commit the mutation but i'm not having much success.

Store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex' 
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex) 

export const store = new Vuex.Store({  
   state: {
      photons: [],

    },
    mutations: {
      setData(state, value) {
        console.log(value)
        state.photons = value
      }
    },
    actions: {
      async getData(context) {
        const data = await axios.get('10.10.10.1:3000/DB')
        console.log(data)
        context.commit('setData', data)
      },

    }   })
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: photons isn't being populated with data

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` print?

Comment: how do you calling that action?

Comment: It isn't logging anything

Comment: Use postman to do a GET request to `10.10.10.1:3000/DB` and see if you receive a valid response.

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim  i'm not calling it anywhere, I would like for the data to start loading when entering the site

Comment: @Stephen it's valid

Comment: @SockMonkey if you're not dispatching the action then its not going to run. Put it in the `created()` method of your initial Vue instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main.js` try to dispatch that action in `mounted` hook :

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import store from './vuex/store';
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,

  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getData')

  }

});
```

Comment: main.js  `new Vue({
  router,
  store,

  mounted() {
    store.dispatch('getData')

  },
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
`   gives me this `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"`

Comment: `this.$store.dispatch('getData')` should work, and did you import `store` correctly?